# Height of Tree query gives 0?

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I'm a bit stuck on the first of a few tasks I have to do this week for my degree and would love some help.
English is not my first language and I don't know most of the translations from german prolog to english prolog, but I'll try my best to explain.

Last week we had to create a "Datatype-Relation" (tree(x)) for 3 different sets.

- functors {f/2,g/1,h/3}
- constants {a,b,c}
- variables {vX,vY,vZ} (note: If I understood correctly, those are not meant as Prolog variables. I don't quite get it though.)

The code for that looked as follows (and was correct):

```
tree(X) :- const(X).
tree(X) :- variable(X).
tree(f(T1,T2)) :- tree(T1), tree(T2).
tree(g(T)) :- tree(T).
tree(h(T1,T2,T3)) :- tree(T1),tree(T2),tree(T3).
const(a).
const(b).
const(c).
variable(vX).
variable(vY).
variable(vZ)
```

Now, I have to create code that calculates the Height, the number of functors and the number of variables and constant in a given tree. I'm already stumped at the height part.

My code for height right now looks like this:

```
height(c,0).
height(X,0).
height(f(T1,T2),N) :- height(T1, N1), height(T2, N2), N is max(N1, N2)+ 1.
height(g(T), N) :- height(T, N1), N is N1 + 1.
height(h(T1, T2, T3), N) :- height(T1, N1), height(T2, N2), height(T3, N3), N23 is max(N2, N3), N is max(N1, N23) + 1.
```

I've tested it with the query: `?- height(tree(f(g(a),b)), Z).` but it always returns "0". I have absolutely no clue what to do. I just don't get Prolog.

Edit: Okay. I saw my mistake. So silly actually. tree(x) obviously doesn't generate the tree itself. I have to leave the tree() part out of the query and it gives me the right answer.

However, it gives me EVERY height leading up to that point as well. For a tree with height 2 it returns 0, 1 and 2. Is there a way to remedy that so it only gives me the height of the whole tree?

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: @brebs Awesome thank you :D. I found the problem itself through that.. Basically a fundamental misunderstanding of Prolog on my part. This however lead to another slight problem. Nothing as big though :D

Comment: You could write more compactly `N is max(N1,max(N2,N3))+1.` in the last rule.

Comment: I ran your code and it gave 0. You say you've edited it, apparently we're still seeing the old code. Can't debug code we can't see! (Meanwhile: why do we have height(c,0) but not height(a,0)? And you definitely don't need height(X,0), which says the height of everything is 0.)